how to register routes at runtime, based on Go package?
I am implementing Task Manager, this is pluggable system.
The system will load the enabled package in /plugins/, then register defined routes in these packages.
Enabled package can be change at runtime, by update the DB value.
main.go
import (
    "database/sql"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net/http"

    _ "github.com/lib/pq" // PostgreSQL driver
    "taskmanager/plugin_manager"
)

func main() {
    // Database Connection
    connStr := "user=postgres dbname=go password=postgres host=localhost sslmode=disable"
    db, err := sql.Open("postgres", connStr)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("Error connecting to database:", err)
    }
    defer db.Close()

    // Check Database Connection
    err = db.Ping()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("Error pinging database:", err)
    }
    fmt.Println("Connected to the database!")

    // Initialize Plugin Manager (pass the db connection)
    pm := plugin_manager.NewPluginManager(db)

    // HTTP Handling
    http.HandleFunc("/", pm.HandleRequest)

    // Start Server
    fmt.Println("Server listening on :8080")
    if err := http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil); err != nil {
        log.Fatal("Error starting server:", err)
    }
}

plugin_manager.go
package plugin_manager

import (
    "database/sql"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "taskmanager/plugins/task" // Update with your actual plugin paths
    "taskmanager/plugins/user"
)

// Plugin represents a plugin module
type Plugin interface {
    Routes() map[string]http.HandlerFunc
}

// PluginManager manages registered plugins
type PluginManager struct {
    db      *sql.DB
    mux     *http.ServeMux
    plugins map[string]Plugin
}

// NewPluginManager creates a new PluginManager
func NewPluginManager(db *sql.DB) *PluginManager {
    pm := &PluginManager{
        db:      db,
        mux:     http.NewServeMux(),
        plugins: make(map[string]Plugin),
    }
    if err := pm.initPlugins(); err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Error initializing plugins: %v", err)
    }
    return pm
}

// RegisterPlugin registers a plugin with the given name
func (pm *PluginManager) RegisterPlugin(name string, plugin Plugin) {
    pm.plugins[name] = plugin
    pm.registerRoutes(plugin.Routes()) // Register routes for the plugin
    log.Printf("Registered plugin: %s", name)
}


// initPlugins loads and initializes enabled plugins from the database
func (pm *PluginManager) initPlugins() error {
    rows, err := pm.db.Query("SELECT name, enabled FROM plugins")
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    defer rows.Close()

    for rows.Next() {
        var name string
        var enabled bool

        if err := rows.Scan(&name, &enabled); err != nil {
            return err
        }

        if !enabled {
            continue // Skip disabled plugins
        }

        plugin, err := loadPlugin(name)
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }
        pm.RegisterPlugin(name, plugin)
        log.Printf("Enabled plugin loaded: %s", name)
    }
    return nil
}
// loadPlugin loads a plugin based on its name
func loadPlugin(name string) (Plugin, error) {
    switch name {
    case "task":
        return task.New(), nil
    case "user":
        return user.New(), nil
    default:
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("unknown plugin: %s", name)
    }
}

// registerRoutes registers routes from the provided route mapping
func (pm *PluginManager) registerRoutes(routes map[string]http.HandlerFunc) {
    for route, handler := range routes {
        pm.mux.HandleFunc(route, handler)
        log.Printf("Registered route: %s", route)
    }
}

// HandleRequest handles incoming requests using the ServeMux
func (pm *PluginManager) HandleRequest(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    pm.mux.ServeHTTP(w, r)
}


plugins/task.go
package task

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
)

type TaskPlugin struct{}

func New() *TaskPlugin { 
    return &TaskPlugin{}
}

func (tp *TaskPlugin) Routes() map[string]http.HandlerFunc {
    return map[string]http.HandlerFunc{
        "/task": tp.handleTask,
    }
}

func (tp *TaskPlugin) handleTask(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    fmt.Fprint(w, "Hello from Task module!")
}


when i run
go run main.go
Every thing work ok, I tested with task plugin, make enable = true in DB then I can access /task
but when I change enable = false, then reload the browser, I still can access /task, it should not be access because I disabled it

A plugin's enabled state is not dynamically updated, it is set when pm.initPlugins is called, so when you set your handlers up.
That initialization code is not rerun each time you access /task, in your case only the registered handlers run when the servers receive a HTTP request.
One easy way to achieve your goal could be to check on every request the value of the enabled field in your database, serving the request if applicable, otherwise unloading the plugin.

thank you. I am implementing a Wordpress-way to do the pluggable system. But maybe It cant implement using Go
